# C Program - Palindrome with functions - almost fully complete one small issue

Tags: c, loops, whitespace, palindrome, strcmp

Is there a way I can remove the white spaces when comparing two strings. The assignment is create a palindrome that is case insensitive and must ignore the white spaces. So far I have

```
void cmpNoCase(char str1[], char str2[]){
   if(strcasecmp(str1, str2)==0){
      printf ("%s is a palindrome.\n", str2);
   } else { ("%s is NOT a palindrome.\n", str2);
}
return;
}
```

and inside main I have this for loop to reverse the first inputted string from the user.

```
for (i=0, j= strlen(input2)-1; i < j; i++, j--){

   index=input2[i];
   input2[i]=input2[j];
   input2[j]=index;
}
```

Note: I have another function which compares the two strings with case sensitivity but takes spaces into account when comparing the index of the string (which is the entered palindrome). The only difference I have in the functions and their for loops are the 'strcmp' for the 1st function, the 2nd being 'strcasecmp' to ignore the case sensitivity.

Comment: This is pertaining to the second inputted string which I called input2.

Comment: Trying to understand your Q...
What if input1 = "A b c d" and input2 = "dcba", will they have to be declared as palindrome as per your requirements?

Answer (score 0):

you may try writing your own comparison function. Do like `while(i<strlen(yourstr){// your logic for comparing the string character by character}` more specifically`while(i<strlen(yourstr)){char a=yourstr[i];
 if(a=' ')
{continue;};
// rest of your comparison code}`
otherwise you can do like: `while((a=yourstring[i])!='\n'){i++;
 if(a=' ')
{continue;}`